# How to pipe gulp-nodemon script to cli program

Tags: node.js, gulp, command-line-interface, nodemon

When running **supervisor app | bunyan** - I have restarting Node app and visualy nicely formatted output, but how to make the same visual if running gulpfile of gulp-nodemon, i.e:

```
var mon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var task('default'      ...
  script : 'app.js',
  ext: ['js', 'jade']   ...)
.on('restart',          ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

See the [Pipe output to somewhere else](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#pipe-output-to-somewhere-else) section in the help. It reveals the `readable` event and the `stdout: false` setting which makes it possible to reformat the log output with bunyan:

```
var mon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var task('default'      ...
    script : 'app.js',
    ext: ['js', 'jade'] 
    stdout: false   ...)
.on('restart',          ...)
.on('readable', function() {
    bunyan = spawn('./node_modules/bunyan/bin/bunyan', [
        '--output', 
        'short',
        '--color'
    ]);

    bunyan.stdout.pipe(process.stdout)
    bunyan.stderr.pipe(process.stderr)

    this.stdout.pipe(bunyan.stdin)
    this.stderr.pipe(bunyan.stdin)
});
```